# No puedo actualizar la columna remember_token - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hola estoy haciendo un login con laravel y si funciona todo bien, el problema que tengo es que al cerrar sesión me sale este error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL 
Server]El nombre de columna 'id' no es válido. (SQL: update 
[Tab_Personal] set [remember_token] = 
SUW7wfTLsMVMeMW36uxATEV8HWI6rYRCGdhsYoDzpZcSj0j2L6UMznauoTmU where 
[id] 
is null)
```

Mi función para cerrar sesión es esta.

```
public function doLogout() {
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/login')->with('msg', 'Gracias por 
    visitarnos!.');
}
```

Comment: Deja ver las migración, el modelo la tabla en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que validar si existe en tu tabla de usuario la columna id.

Puedes editar tu tabla para que la PK sea la columna `id`. Tambien puedes decirle a laravel quién sera tu PK.

Definiendo llave primaria(PK) laravel en el archvo

> Ruta donde debes poner el codigo ***app\User.php***

```
$primaryKey ='idPersonalizado';
```

Con ésto ya solucionas tu error. Ten en cuenta que al cerrar sesión se registra un token y fecha de actualizacion de la tabla, puedes crear los campos también si no los tienes. **remember_token** y **updated_at**.